# Determining visibility of a text box based on the table record

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I am working on a project of attendance sheet using visual basic 6.0 and Microsoft Access.

Now in this I have a combobox `subject`, and I have text boxes of `roll number`, and indexed combo boxes of registering 'attendance' below the subject.

The subject combo box have 3 subjects. Each student can select only 2 subjects from that.

Now, when I select a subject from the combo box above, I want to make visible only the text boxes of the students, that have taken that subject. Other text boxes and combo boxes should become invisible.

And also I have a master reocords of students mentioning their roll number, names and their subjects.

So can anyone help me regarding this ?

Comment: Apply filter to form so only desired student records are displayed.

Comment: But, each time, while inserting attendance into the form it must automatically filter according to the subject selected in the combo box.

Comment: And that requires code which you have not attempted and not provided any for analysis. A combobox used to input filter criteria should be UNBOUND. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html